# cccheck.exe pegging CPU and taking up lots of memory

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Running a fully updated Visual Studio 2012 instance.

I've been noticing while trying to debug that occasionally my system will start to bog down. When this happens, looking at the process list I've noticed that MSBuild.exe always has a sub processed called cccheck.exe which is sucking up on the order of 60% of the CPU power and somewhere between 3 and 5 gigs of ram.

After some research, cccheck.exe is what runs the the compile time checks for code contracts which I use extensively in code. I love them. They're great. But I don't think they need to run every time I go to debug.

The problem though is when I debug, this process is basically still running while I'm in my code instead of shutting itself down or something. This causes MSBuild.exe to keep running. It makes me wonder if I don't have something configured incorrectly as far as running it because it seems like a very odd behavior to have.

I can resolve the issue by killing the cccheck.exe process. But MSBuild.exe will restart another cccheck.exe. If instead kill MSBuild.exe, everything returns to normal and I can debug without spending thirty seconds to step forward one line.

does anyone have any advice as to how to resolve this issue? I'm sure I'd need to give more information before any real advice could be given but I'm not sure what to supply. I've done a bunch of googling on this and most of the postings I've found are old. I've tried a few things they've recommended (updates and such) but nothing has worked.

Comment: I'm facing same issue in Visual studio 2010 :(